# How can we decide whether or not to provide default empty implementation (Defender Method) for an interface method?

Tags: java

Currently, I have an interface which looks like this

```
public interface SortInfoDialogListener {
    void onSortInfoSelected(SortInfo sortInfo);
    void onSortInfoDialogDismiss(DialogInterface dialog);
}
```

---

Since most of the implementors are not interested in `onSortInfoDialogDismiss`, I was wondering, should I make it as an empty defender method?

```
public interface SortInfoDialogListener {
    void onSortInfoSelected(SortInfo sortInfo);
    default void onSortInfoDialogDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    }
}
```

---

I was wondering, what else factors I should consider, before making an interface function having an empty defender method?

I try to find answers in Effective Java 3 Item 20 and Item 21. But, still can't derive a concrete conclusion yet.

Comment: If *most of the implementors are not interested in `onSortInfoDialogDismiss`*, why note split this into two different interfaces (with the one declaring `onSortInfoDialogDismiss` being a sub-interface of the other)?

Answer (score 5):

SOLID principles states to segregate interfaces as per the requirement. Currently i could see onSortInfoDialogDismiss method is not required for many implementors.

Try to extract onSortInfoDialogDismiss() to another interface, so it could be implemented on demand.

keep current interface with onSortInfoSelected() alone, as below.

```
public interface SortInfoDialogListener {
    void onSortInfoSelected(SortInfo sortInfo);
}
```

Hope this helps.